# IE8 cuts off piece of H1 after scrolling

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

So I'm stuck with this annoying and minor IE8 problem. When  I'm scrolling it seems like IE cuts off some piece of my H1 titles. I made a video so it's clear what is happening.

The HTML & CSS are very large, so before I'm going to include all the HTML and CSS I would like to know if someone knows an possible cause. Or maybe it's an known IE problem?

The titles (BRACELETS, NECKLACES, ..) are H1´s with z-index set to 999.

The video can be found here http://imageshack.us/clip/my-videos/607/wcw.mp4/

Comment: Are you sure? As it seams that it took just more time to render.. That is just a slow browser and not "cuts off"  as you think

Comment: Yes the H1 uses an @font-face (and is placed whitin an font-family as the first one in line).

Comment: @footy the computer I made the video on is pretty high-end (3,5ghz quad, Radeon HD9670 and 8GB RAM). Could IE be that worse?

Comment: Yes i personally think that its just IE's lack of rendering quality. But any code to see what *actually* happens will be good other than guessing.

Comment: You must provide a link to your actual site if you want this to be resolved. If you can't provide that, a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo that also shows the bug would suffice.

Comment: My client doesn't want me to disclose anything before official release. I will cut out the important pieces and try to reproduce the problem on another page, but I'll get to that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

A live code sample would be great to explore. My only guess based on the video (which is very helpful in this scenario  nice!), is that IE8 is choking and lagging on rendering items as you are scrolling. Is there any markup changes tied to scroll events or perhaps some CSS "fixed" items on your page?

Answer (score 0):

i know it's a very old question but i think it could help others

I found myself having the same problem with a free-for-commercial-use font

The solution i found was playing around with the **line-height** CSS property
In some sports setting it to the height of the div, in others to the font-size, in others to a little bit more than that

In my experience it changes from font to font and from font-size to font-size